# Are asynchronous batch queries also limited by maximum response size?

Tags: google-bigquery

I intend to run batch queries in order to amend some fields value and insert the result in another table. As an example:

```
bq --nosync query --batch --destination_table=datasetId.anotherTable "SELECT field0+1, field1, field2 FROM datasetId.someTable"
```

But I get this error:

```
Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed  
---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- ----------------- 
query      FAILURE   06 Sep 11:09:58   0:00:04                     

Errors encountered during job execution. Response too large to return.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently batch queries have the same limit on response size as non-batch queries.

However, you can use the --allow_large_results flag and set a destination table for queries that have larger result sizes.

Comment: Thanks. That means there is no easy way, using queries from bq, to update an entire table without exporting first as CSV or process it programmatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is correct, there is no easy way to update an entire table without re-importing it. This is a common request, however, and your feedback helps us prioritize it as a work item.

Comment: Please share any example of running batch process on GAE.